# To prove a sufficient and necessary condition of a quadratic form to equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, sesquilinear-forms

The question is the following:

**Let X a vector space and $B: V \times V \rightarrow K$ a positive semi-definite form. Show that $q_B(y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow B(x,y)=0$, $\forall$ $x$ $\in$ $V$, where $\ q_B(y)\ $ is the quadratic form $\ B(y,y)\ $.**

Is it because $q_B = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_i \bar{x_j}$? Similar type proof as to proving linear independence?

Answer (score 0):

- $\ B(x,y)=0\ \forall x\in V\implies q_B(y)=0\ $ is trivial (put $\ x=y\ $ in the antecedent of the implication)
- $\  q_B(y)=0\implies B(x,y)=0\ \forall x\in V\ $ follows from the [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality: $$|B(x,y)|\le\sqrt{q_B(x)q_B(y)}\ ,$$ which holds for any positive
  semi-definite bilinear form. The proof is essentially the same as for
  any inner product.

Comment: $\ q_B(y)\ $ is indeed the quadratic form $\ B(y,y)\ $. Will edit the question.

Comment: Could you give a more detailed explanation? Wasn't able to solve it. Thanks!